# How to get the year in 2 digits in php?

Tags: php

I want to get the year in 2 digits like **15**.

using the php date() function

```
echo date("Y");
```

but this returns the full year.

any help is much appriciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Format a date string in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654101/format-a-date-string-in-php)

Comment: That is not a duplicate of this question.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Change the upper case 'Y' to lower case 'y'

```
echo date("y");
```

PHP documentation

```
y   A two digit representation of a year
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use substr() method of PHP to get the last two digit of a year as follows.

```
$year =  2011;
$year = substr( $year, -2);
```

The above code gives 11 as a output which is the last two digit of 2011.

Answer (score 10):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

See this documentation. It's `date("y")`.
So a lowercase y instead of Y.